# Dojo: FilteringSelect and ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.5 for building a Web Application. Currently, I'm trying to make a Form to fill some data in the Database, and this form needs a ComboBox with some pre-loaded data for the user to select. What I'm trying to do is declare that combo with `ItemFileWriteStore` as data source and `FilteringSelect` as the Widget. The `ItemFileWriteStore` goes like this:

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="itemsStore" url="rest/items">
</div>
```

The `rest/items` URI return this:

```
{"items":[{"id":1003,"description":"And Item","name":"Items"}]}
```

And my Combo widget goes like this:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="item_edited" 
store="itemsStore" searchAttr="name" id="item_edited" required="true" />
```

When I load the form I can see the `FilteringSelect` with the data that comes from the REST Service. But when I select the only item in the Combo and make a POST request to persist the data, I'm seeing this in Firebug:

```
Parameters (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

form_item          123
another_form_item  foo
item_edited        1
```

So I expect thed attribute `id` from the JSON type (that for the only item returned is **1003**) to be sent to the Server, but I'm getting son ordinal position instead. How do I tell `FilteringSelect` to use the `id` attribute of the JSON returned as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the identifier attribute in the JSON returned from the URI:

```
{"identifier" : "id", "label" : "name", "items":[{"id":1003,"description":"And Item","name":"Items"}]}
```